# Is there a way to store and retrieve a password in a file from a batch script?

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, vbscript

```
@ECHO OFF
DFC.EXE get /isfrozen

IF Errorlevel 1 GOTO Frozen
IF Errorlevel 0 GOTO Thawed

:Frozen
Echo Errorlevel 1 Computer is Frozen, Thawing Now
DFC.EXE fakepassword123 /BOOTTHAWED
Echo
Goto END

:Thawed
Echo Errorlevel 0 Computer is Not Frozen
Echo
Goto END

:END
Exit
```

I am trying to run a very simple batch file but I don't want the password stored in plain text if someone were to edit it.

Right now the DFC.exe password line is where the password is stored.

Is there a way to hide this password in another file and call it from there?

Answer (score 9):

You can use PowerShell to store the password on disk in a way that (by default) is only retrievable by the currently executing user on the computer it was created on. If you can't write your entire script in PowerShell, you can at least do this by calling `powershell.exe` during your script.

## If you want to use the credential from a single machine and user

To create the credential file (this will prompt you for the credential, **the username doesn't matter in this case but must be provided**):

```
powershell.exe -c "Get-Credential | Export-CliXml cred.xml"
```

`Export-CliXml` is a special cmdlet that serializes a PowerShell object to disk, and with some edge caveats (like don't try doing this with a COM object and expect it to work), can usually be used to read the object back into another session as we do below. And to read it in from your script to a variable and use it in your command:

```
for /f %i in ('powershell.exe -c "( Import-CliXml cred.xml ).GetNetworkCredential().Password"') do set PASSWORD=%i
DFC.EXE %PASSWORD% /BOOTTHAWED
```

We need to obtain the network credential so we can get a usable password as part of that command. If you do find yourself needing the username as well in other commands, you can also get that in a similar fashion:

```
for /f %i in ('powershell.exe -c "( Import-CliXml cred.xml ).UserName"') do set USERNAME=%i
```

In the case of the username, it is not encrypted so you don't need to return the network credential to obtain a useable username.

## If you want to use the credential from multiple machines and users

Above, we leverage `Get-Credential` to create the initial credential for its simplicity, but it's not strictly necessary to build a credential object with it.

If you need to decrypt the credential from multiple machines or users, it's a little more complicated. You won't be able to leverage `Get-Credential` and will have to build the credential yourself, and store only the password in a file (you could store the username as well but for this case).

### Preparing the secret

To prepare the credential, first we'll need to create a key file. This is more complex than being able to use `Get-Credential` but **you only have to do these steps when you generate the keyfile or password file the first time**. It's best to do this step from `powershell.exe`:

```
$keyFile = "C:\path\to\keyfile.key"

# you can adjust this number for different levels of AES encryption
# 32 = 256 bits
# 24 = 192 bits
# 16 = 128 bits
$key = New-Object Byte[] 32
[Security.Cryptography.RNGCryptoServiceProvider]::Create().GetBytes($key)

# Save the key file to disk
$key | Out-File $keyFile
```

Now that we have the key file, we can store your password to disk using it (remember, this time we are just storing the password in the file, not a `PSCredential` object). Once again, this is best done from `powershell.exe` like with the previous step:

```
# Save your password in a file so you don't have it plaintext in your history
$insecurePassFile = "C:\path\to\insecurePassFile.txt"

# This will be the encrypted password outfile
$securePassFile = "C:\path\to\securePassFile.txt"

# This can also be a UNC path if on a share
$keyFile = "C:\path\to\keyfile.key"

# Read the key in
$key = Get-Content $keyFile

# Read the plaintext password in and convert it to a secure string using our key
$password = Get-Content $insecurePassFile | Select-Object -First 1 | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force | ConvertFrom-SecureString -key $key

# Write the encrypted password out to a file to be read in later using our key
$password | Out-File $securePassFile
```

Now you will have your encrypted password file saved to `$securePassFile`. **At this point you can copy your password file and key to a location on the network.**

### Using the credential in your batch script

Now we're going back to batch world. To read the password in, you'll need to know the location of the password file and key file, and have permissions to access both of these. I apologize, but this is going to be a long PowerShell command to fit on one line:

```
for /f %i in ('powershell.exe -c "$key = Get-Content \\server.domain.tld\share\path\to\keyfile.key; [System.Net.NetworkCredential]::new("", ( Get-Content \\server.domain.tld\share\path\to\password.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key ) ).Password"') do set PASSWORD=%i
```

That was a mouthful, so let's break it down:

1. The batch `for` loop is the "magic" required to set a variable to a command's output. Eventually sets the `PASSWORD` variable to the output of the PowerShell command. IMO the people who wrote the command prompt are masochists XD.
2. This begins the actual decryption process. First we need to read the `$key` from the key file. Without this we can't decrypt our password from the password file.
3. We create a new network credential that we can extract the password from by creating a new `System.Net.NetworkCredential` object. The first parameter is the username (which we don't need here, an empty string works) and the second is the `SecureString` password:
4. For the password argument, we read the password from the file and decrypt it to a proper `SecureString` using the key from our key file.
5. From the resulting `NetworkCredential` object we are able to read the `Password` property which is a usable password we can return.
6. As part of the original batch `for` loop, `PASSWORD` is set to the output of the previous PowerShell command, which in this case is the `Password` property of the `NetworkCredential` we built.

## Treat your key like any other sensitive password

> If you provided your own key, make sure to store your key somewhere secure. Only the users and machines that should have access to it should be able to read it. Ideally, credentials and secrets should be stored and retrieved from a secrets vault (e.g. Hashicorp Vault, Keepass, etc.) but file ACLs can be used to control who can access this information as well.

---

Do note that when the account password changes, you will have to regenerate `cred.xml` if you are relying on the default encryption behavior.

Comment: Bender that is absolutely amazing thank you very much! I will most definitely use this. One problem though is it wont let me store it with the username field left blank.

Comment: I mentioned that above already, but since the username doesn't matter here you can put anything in for it. Make sure to use a real username though if you ever need to store both the username and password though!

Comment: Thank you soo much Bender! Your are the absolute greatest!

Comment: No problem. I have to admit though, writing the batch code to set a command's output to a variable reminded me of how much I hate the command prompt syntax lol.

Comment: I'd recommend learning it, yeah. It's a much cleaner syntax, and much more powerful than cmd.exe.

Comment: So is it possible to call this cred.xml from a remote computer using \\server\path ? I Need to run this script from a server to 100 computers and I don't have the time to go on each one and save this cred file. Im going to try it monday but I thought I'd ask anyway.

Would I just input it into for /f %i in ('powershell.exe -c "( Import-CliXml \\server\fakenetworkpath\fakefolder\cred.xml ?

Comment: Yes but you need to provide your own key to encrypt and decrypt the password from multiple machines. I'll try to find an example this weekend and update my answer.

Comment: Alright, I've added the instructions on how to create a keyfile, use it to store an encrypted password in a file, and how to retrieve that password using the keyfile you created. It's a doozy, but most of the work only needs to be done to create the keyfile and password file. Reading it in is still fairly simple.

Comment: I think there's a way to use a certificate as a key, but I don't know the details.

Comment: There is but I can't remember offhand how to do it either. I usually just rely on the default DPAPI behavior because it's so easy.

Comment: Hey Bender, this is so amazing thank you very much again!

How do i save $securePassFile password file and key to a location on the network? What kind of file is it?

Comment: Both would just be plain text files after they're generated. All I mean by "save to a location on the network" is to save both files to a network share somewhere. For example, a mapped network drive or UNC path to a network shared folder.